# Pronoun Usage (on or on it)

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, american-english, british-english

Which of the following is more accurate?

1) You have one day to solve the exam on.

2) You have one day to solve the exam on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is correct.

You don't solve exam. You take/sit an exam. Or you solve a problem.

3) You have one day to solve the problem.

4) You have one day to take/sit the exam.

You don't need any pronoun or preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the two. You should say:

3. You have one day to solve the problem.

Comment: Why is the first not correct? solving the exam is on a specific day.

Comment: "on" will be used in adverbials of time: *The problem will be solved **on** a certain day*. In the structure you proposed, "on" is not needed or used.